# Serving Vue.js Server Side Rendering on Node-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to get the Hackernews 2.0 demo up and running on my Digital Ocean droplet, but I fail.

- `npm run start` spins up the server on :8080.
- `npm run build` builds for production.

The defined build tasks are defined here:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.client.config.js --progress --hide-modules",
    "build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.server.config.js --progress --hide-modules"
  }
```

...and [the entire repo is here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0).

But what should I execute to serve as a :80 website?

I asked on Gitter.im, on the Vue-channel, but with zero success.

Anyone?

Comment: Can we see some source code ? its very dificult to answer a question with not enough details on it

Comment: @mtsdev: I've updated the question.

Comment: check the answer. the last option its a blind shot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to execute anything special. Simply change the definiton of listen port inside the application, on line 89 of server.js

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 80   // << changed here
```

or export env Var PORT prior to start. In  linux, something like

```
export PORT=80 && npm start
```

EDIT:

or even create you own  start script on package.json

```
"start80": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production PORT=80 node server",
```

(maybe- i dont' know exactly how cross-env works)